# How to change the title of the 'proof' environment?

Tags: pdftex, environments, proof-package

I want to change the title of my `proof` environment, so that instead of *Demostración.*, the proof starts with *Proof.* I attach a screenshot to help explain myself better.

[image]

Please help. Thank you :D.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing the title of your posting so that it relates more directly to the body of the query. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example of code that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you (a) employ the `amsthm` package (since it provides an environment called `proof`) and (b) load the `babel` package with the language option `spanish` (since it changes the value of `\proofname` to `Demostración` if Spanish language rules are in effect). Please advise if this is not the case.

If my working assumptions are correct, I can think of two ways for you to achieve your formatting objective.

- Load the `babel` package with both `english` and `spanish` as the language options and issue the instruction

  ```
  \selectlanguage{english}
  ```

  somewhere before you start writing mainly in English. (This approach means that if you later issue the instruction `\selectlanguage{spanish}`, the title of the `proof` environment switches back to `Demostración`.)
- If you want `\proofname` to evaluate to `Proof` *globally*, i.e., in both the English and Spanish language parts of your document, you should issue the instruction

  ```
  \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\proofname{Proof}}
  ```

  in the preamble.

---

The following example illustrates the use of the first suggestion.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{4} % just for this example
\addtocounter{prop}{10}

\begin{prop} \dots \end{prop}
\begin{proof} \dots \end{proof}

\selectlanguage{english} 
\begin{prop} \dots \end{prop}
\begin{proof} \dots \end{proof}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\begin{prop} \dots \end{prop}
\begin{proof} \dots \end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bernard - Thanks for fixing the error! :-)

Comment: I'm also glad when someone fixes my typos! I guess it was a *la psus calami* in your case :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm! :D

Comment: @AdriánNaranjo - You're most welcome! Just curious; which of the two methods did you end up choosing?

Comment: To evaluate proof globally.